# How to maintain session in subdomains with cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I want to maintain session between my two domains, alpha.domain.com and wwww.domain.com. I have already done changes in bootstrap.php

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");
```

and also put security level to 'low' in core.php, but not working.

Comment: do you clear all cookie for alpha.domain.com and wwww.domain.com before test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the cake way of setting the [cookie domain](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html).

```
public $components = array('Cookie');
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Cookie->domain = 'example.com';
}
```

NOTE: This is for CakePHP 2.0

Comment: I have cleared the cache also before testing and also used the code of Chuck in cookie.php, but dosn't work

Comment: It doesn't mean it's wrong and should be down voted. What version of PHP and CakePHP are you running @zeflex?

Comment: Do you have a pastebin of code that can show how you're using it? @zeflex

Comment: @zeflex this was answered 3 years ago for version 2.0. While it may not work on version 2.5.3, it doesn't make this answer incorrect. I'm not certain why the down votes. This works as explained.

Comment: Sorry for that. My mistake. When I try to upvote is says "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: @zeflex No worries. It could have been more clear in the answer.